# Windows Batch Script that Pings List of Computers and Runs Script on Online PCs

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will search for a file on a list of 100+ PCs and output 1 of 3 things: if the PC has the file, if it doesn't or if it's not awake.  The last part is the part I can't figure out. I want the script to create 3 separate csv files- HAS_FILE, NEEDS_FILE and NOT_THERE. I can successfully run this code (assuming all PCs in 'ComputerList' are "up"):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\ComputerList.csv) do (
IF EXIST "\\%%i\c$\Program Files\F5 Networks\iControlSnapIn\f5.ico". (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\HAS_FILE.csv
) ELSE (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\NEEDS_FILE.csv
)
)
```

After I wrote that script, I realized that assuming 100+ computers on my network would be up was dumb. If the script above hits a PC that is offline, it will falsely report that it needs the file. When actually, I want it to report that it's "NOT_THERE." I thought the best way to do this was to add a ping to the beginning of the batch and this is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\ComputerList.csv) do (
ping %%i -n 1 -w 100
IF "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\NOT_THERE.csv
) ELSE IF EXIST "\\%%i\c$\Program Files\F5 Networks\iControlSnapIn\f5.ico". (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\HAS_FILE.csv
) ELSE (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\NEEDS_FILE.csv
)
)
```

I've played around with this a bunch but can't get it to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

EDIT: I should tell you my results- for a test, I narrowed my csv down to 4 PCs- 1 that has the file, 1 that doesn't and 2 that are offline. The script hangs about half way through (after it pings the 1st offline PC) for about 10 seconds. When it completes, I only get 2 of the 3 output files I should be getting. It successfully reports the PC that contains the file but groups the other 3 in the NEEDS_FILE log. It doesn't report the 2 offline computers in the NOT_THERE csv. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again!

EDIT2: I may have found a reason why my script is not reporting PCs that are offline. For some reason, the script seems to be capturing the first "errorlevel" of the first PC on the list. The first PC is up so it passes the "0" errorlevel to the other 3 PCs. I changed the first PC on my list to one that's off and it passed the "1" error level to the remaining 3. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Are your computer lists in the file as one ip/name per line?  It lists a .csv file which is normally `a,b,c,d` format and that won't work in your code as it is.

Comment: Yes, I am using one hostname per line. I also used a txt file to test and got the same results :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! It was the "%" signs around the errorlevel. Here is the code that worked:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\ComputerList.csv) do (
ping %%i -n 1 -w 100
IF errorlevel 1 (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\NOT_THERE.csv
) ELSE IF EXIST "\\%%i\c$\Program Files\F5 Networks\iControlSnapIn\f5.ico". (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\HAS_FILE.csv
) ELSE (
echo %%i >> \\networkdrive\NEEDS_FILE.csv
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF %errorlevel% EQU "1" (
```

will never work.
I think, you meant:

```
IF "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" (
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Sorry! Typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

insert this line right before the ping. You may have extra characters in the csv file

`echo.i=%%i]`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that still didn't work. I used a txt file in my testing and it still doesn't work.

Comment: That was not intended to make it work.  It was intended to show if %%i is what you expect and to see if there are trailing characters, etc.